# Mount F2FS *.bin file premission problem

Tags: 18.04, f2fs

Iam trying to mount a F2FS partition but iam having problems with the premission.

Iam running

```
sudo mount -t f2fs -o rw /home/***/Desktop/file.bin /media/mount/
```

This results in the bin file mounted to /media/mount/, i can op the mount and see the directorys.
When opening a dir i get "cannot open directory '.' Premision denied"

i tried thing like

```
chmod 777 on dirs 
sudo chmod a+rwx /media/mount/
```

etc

No luck! anybody an idea?

Kind regards